# Monotouch - My app does not show up in Settings App anymore

Tags: ios, ipad, xamarin.ios

For some unknown reasons, my app does show up in the iOS General Setting App along with all other app like it use to.

Moreover it the Debugger does not connect to the app neither!

Any clues?

Comment: Are you using a Release build?

Comment: I have even tried to restore my iPad to factory default still no luck. I tried another sample app from mono touch and it works, so it has to be an app issue, any clues anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I turned out to be the Root.plist in the Settings.bundle that is causing problem when upgrading to iOS 5.1.1.

Could be a bug?!